# Functions satisfying $(b-a)f'(\tfrac{a+b}{2}) = f(b)- f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ be a differientable real function such that $$(b-a)f'(\tfrac{a+b}{2}) = f(b)- f(a)$$
for all reals $a,b$.

> Is $f$ polynomial of degree $\leq 2$ ?

Comment: What do _you_ think? You've been here long enough to know we appreciate some of your own thoughts in a question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.

The condition on $f$  is equivalent to

$$f(x+h)-f(x-h)=2f'(x)h\tag{1}$$
for all reals $x$ and $h$. Letting $h=1$ in $(1)$, we can conclude that $f$ is twice differentiable.  Therefore, we can differentiate both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $h$ twice, which gives us

$$f''(x+h)-f''(x-h)=0. \tag{2}$$
Since $x$ and $h$  are arbitrary in $(2)$, $f''$ must be a constant function, i.e. $f$ is a polynomial of degree no more than $2$.

Comment: How does letting $h=1$ let us conclude that the function is twice differentiable and how do we show that no other non-polynomial function has second derivative constant?

Comment: @Rhaldryn . For all $x$ we have $ f'(x)=(f(x+1)-f(x-1))/2.$ The RHS of this is differentiable with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Rhaldryn . (1). Theorem: If $c'(x)=0$ for all $x$ then $c$ is constant...... (2). Theorem. If $a(x)$ is continuous and $b'(x)=a(x)$ for all $x,$ and $b(0)=0$ then $b(x)=\int_0^x a(t)dt.$ Proof: Let $c(x)=b(x)-\int_0^xa(t)dt .$ By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,$ c'(x)=0.$  So by (1), $ c(x)=c(0)=0$ for all $x......$ (3). If $f'' $is constantly $K$ then by (2) with $b(x)=f'(x)-f'(0)$  and $ a(x)=K$ we have $f'(x)-f'(0)=\int_0^x Kdt=Kx.....$  So  by (2) with $b(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and $a(x)=f'(0)+Kx$ we have$ f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^xa(t)dt=xf'(0)+Kx^2/2$.

Comment: Does there exists any function $f$ other than the polynomials??