# Prove that the only functions that satisfy the following are polynomials

Tags: calculus

[image]

if we put $x=\frac{h}{2}$, then we obtain

$f(\frac{3h}{2})-f(\frac{h}{2}) = hf'(h)$

let $h=2$ and so $f(3)-f(1) = 2f'(2)$

I dont see how to procceed. Any hints?

Comment: They want you to do something with the mean value theorem. It says that it's only quadratic polynomials that have the derivative at the midpoint of any interval equal to the difference quotient over that interval.

Comment: This follows immediately from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522477/functions-satisfying-b-af-tfracab2-fb-fa